# How do I solve two equations with DSolve?

Tags: differential-equations, numerics

I used the following command:

```
  {Z, Y} = {z, y} /. 
AsymptoticDSolveValue[{y'''[t] == (-c1 - t^2)*z[t], 
  z'''[t] == (c2 + t^2)*y[t], y[0] == 0, y'[0] == 0, 
  y''[0] == 10}, {z, y}, t] // FullSimplify // First
```

However, there is a problem with the variable x^2 or something and I get:

```
ReplaceAll::reps: {DSolve[{(y^(3))[t]==(-c1-Power[<<2>>]) y[t],(z^(3))[t]==(c2+t^2) z[t],y[0]==0,(y^\[Prime])[0]==0,(y^\[Prime]\[Prime])[0]==10},{z,y},t]} is neither a list of replacement rules nor a valid dispatch table, and so cannot be used for replacing.
```

It is all in one dimension, x, where y and z are the independent variables. What should I do here?

[image]
Thanks!

Comment: Are you sure that the set of differential equations is correctly written? You have two ODEs for y'''(t) and none for x(t).

Comment: Original form changed.. Please see above, answering @dpravos point.

Comment: What is `x[t]`?  You have an arbitrary, undefined function in there. It's no wonder Mathematica is not giving a solution.

Comment: @user287546 The edit doesn't answer dpravos's comment.

Comment: Also, re the now deleted MATLAB comment: do you want a symbolic or numerical solution? MATLAB does only numerical (unless you have MuPad)

Comment: Please see update in the edit.

Comment: `DSolve` can't find symbolic solution,but `AsymptoticDSolveValue` can find general series solution.

Comment: Thanks, do I only need to replace Dsolve with AsymptoticDSolveValue  ?

Comment: I solved equation in the picture not in yours code.Yours code is a load of nonsense?

Comment: True, I edited and corrected it now.

Comment: What initial conditions are for `z[t]` function?

Comment: y[0] == z[0] == 0, y'[0] ==  z'[0] == 0, 
  y''[0] ==  z''[0] == 10

Answer (score 4):

```
DSolve[{y'''[t] == (-c1 - t^2)*z[t], z'''[t] == (c2 + t^2)*y[t], 
y[0] == 0, y'[0] == 0, y''[0] == 10, z[0] == 0, z'[0] == 0, 
z''[0] == 10}, {z[t], y[t]}, t]

(* Return unevaluated *)
```

Solution by:`AsymptoticDSolveValue` works only in version `11.3` or above.

```
ClearAll["Global`*"];
Remove["Global`*"];(* Clear and Remove all variables *)

{Z, Y} = AsymptoticDSolveValue[{
y'''[t] == (-c1 - t^2)*z[t], 
z'''[t] == (c2 + t^2)*y[t], 
y[0] == 0, y'[0] == 0, y''[0] == 10, 
z[0] == 0, z'[0] == 0, z''[0] == 10}, 
{z, y}, {t, 0, 10}]

(* {5 t^2 + (c2 t^5)/12 + t^7/42 - (c1 c2 t^8)/
 4032 + ((-7 c1 - 2 c2) t^10)/60480, 
 5 t^2 - (c1 t^5)/12 - t^7/42 - (c1 c2 t^8)/
 4032 + ((-2 c1 - 7 c2) t^10)/60480}*)

Plot[Evaluate[{Z, Y} /. c1 -> 1 /. c2 -> 1], {t, 0, 3}, 
PlotLegends -> {"z[t]", "y[t]"}]
```

[image]

`AsymptoticDSolveValue` function is very sensitive for changes initial conditions.

If I only change:`z[1] == 0` it can't find series solution.

**A numeric solution:**

```
c1 = 1;
c2 = 1;
sol = NDSolve[
{y'''[t] == (-c1 - t^2)*z[t],
z'''[t] == (c2 + t^2)*y[t], 
y[0] == 0, y'[0] == 0, y''[0] == 10,
z[0] == 0, z'[0] == 0, 
z''[0] == 10}, {z, y}, {t, 0, 2},WorkingPrecision -> 30]

Plot[Evaluate[{z[t] /. sol, y[t] /. sol}], {t, 0, 2.1}, 
PlotLegends -> {"z[t]", "y[t]"}]
```

[image]

```
Plot[Evaluate[{Evaluate[{Z, Y} /. c1 -> 1 /. c2 -> 1], z[t] /. sol, 
y[t] /. sol}], {t, 0, 2.7}, 
PlotLegends -> {"z[t]", "y[t]", "z[t]-numeric", "y[t]-numeric"}]
```

[image]

**OP request:**

```
sol[c1_, c2_] := 
NDSolve[{y'''[t] == (-c1 - t^2)*z[t],
z'''[t] == (c2 + t^2)*y[t], 
y[0] == 0, y'[0] == 0, y''[0] == 10,
z[0] == 0, z'[0] == 0, z''[0] == 10},
{z, y}, {t, 0, 3}];(* You can change initial conditions *)

Manipulate[
Plot[Evaluate[{z[t] /. sol[a, b], y[t] /. sol[a, b]}], {t, 0, 3}, 
PlotRange -> {{0, 3}, {-10, 20}}, PlotStyle -> Thick, 
Filling -> {1 -> {2}}], {{a, 1.3, "c1"}, 0, 10, 
Appearance -> "Labeled"}, {{b, 2.5, "c2"}, 0, 10, 
Appearance -> "Labeled"}]
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot Marius. Is there a way to use this:

Manipulate[Plot[Evaluate[{X[t], Y[t]} /. {c1 -> a, c2 -> b}], {t, 0, 10}, 
  PlotRange -> {0, 1}, PlotStyle -> Thick, Filling -> {1 -> {2}}], 
  {{a, 1.3, "c1"}, 1, 3, Appearance -> "Labeled"}, 
  {{b, 2.5, "c2"}, 1, 3, Appearance -> "Labeled"}]

to study the change of the constants c1 and c2?

Thanks again! Best wishes

Comment: I correct my answer.

Comment: Hi @Mariusz Iwaniuk , I don't get your results for the "AsymptoticDSolveValue" method. I copied and paste your command and get:

Set::shape: Lists {Removed[Z],Removed[Y]} and Removed[AsymptoticDSolveValue][{(Removed[y]^(3))[Removed[t]]==(-Removed[c1]-Removed[t]^2) Removed[z][Removed[t]],(Removed[z]^(3))[Removed[t]]==(Removed[c2]+Removed[t]^2) Removed[y][Removed[t]],Removed[y][0]==0,(Removed[y]^\[Prime])[0]==0,(<<7>>[y]^\[Prime]\[Prime])[0]==10,Removed[z][0]==0,(Removed[z]^\[Prime])[0]==0,(Removed[z]^\[Prime]\[Prime])[0]==10},{<<1>>,<<7>>[y]},<<1>>] are not the same shape.

Comment: @user287546. `AsymptoticDSolveValue` function was introduced in Mathematica `11.3`.Do You have `11.3` version?

Comment: No. I have 11.0. However, I will get 11.3 in a month or so! I can try then! Thanks!

Comment: @user287546 . You can try now. It free on Wolfram Cloud, only need a `Sign in`.https://develop.wolframcloud.com/

Comment: Fantastic, I was not aware of this! Thanks again @Mariusz!

Comment: Hi @Mariusz Iwaniuk, are the solutions using AsymptoticDSolveValue approximations using an asymptotic simplificaition?  Thanks!

Comment: @Yes.Read `Details and Options`: http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/AsymptoticDSolveValue.html

Comment: Thanks @Mariusz Iwaniuk. One thing I was looking at, the two solutions given in the example above of yours: (* {5 t^2 + (c2 t^5)/12 + t^7/42 - (c1 c2 t^8)/
 4032 + ((-7 c1 - 2 c2) t^10)/60480, 
 5 t^2 - (c1 t^5)/12 - t^7/42 - (c1 c2 t^8)/
 4032 + ((-2 c1 - 7 c2) t^10)/60480}*) are not the same, but they also only reflect the same plot (y(t)) . If one plots each, they appear the same plot. What is the difference between the two?
Thanks

Comment: @user287546. Plots are the same,You need add a option: `WorkingPrecision -> 30` in `NDSolve`

Comment: Thanks @Mariusz Iwaniuk, it still gives two solutions which are the same. If there is no difference, why do they both result? Thanks!

Comment: @user287546.I made a comparison, numeric method vs  approximations by series to determine if I have made a mistake somewhere.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/75726/discussion-between-user287546-and-mariusz-iwaniuk).

Comment: The last method you showed (OP request)  does not work in cloud, is that required a stationary version of Mathematica 11.3 for it? I get the error msg: "SetDelayed
:Tag List in zInterpolatingFunction{{0.,5.5}},{5,7,3,{147},{4},0,0,0,0,Automatic,{},{},False},{1},Developer`PackedArrayForm,{0,49,98},0.,0.,5.,0.,
2.5248×10
-9
,41,4.99819,-0.0525065,0.0398735,0.631371,538,{Automatic},1[1
] is Protected"
Thanks

Comment: @For me works fine.Copy code``ClearAll["Global`*"];
Remove["Global`*"];`` and exectue to clears all variables. Or try a new file(session).

Comment: Thanks again @Mariusz. Your help has been vital!